# Toolbar for Bold 9900

Tags: blackberry, toolbar, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Can we add a custom toolbar to a blackberry bold 9900 screen?

I have tried it but then how to access those buttons (since it is not touchscreen)?

Can you suggest any alternate option if toolbar is not compatible?

Comment: Take a look [at this example](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-tabbed-view-screens/ta-p/444969). It should work for all recent Java BlackBerry devices.  It doesn't matter if the device is not a touchscreen.  The user can scroll from tab to tab, and select them, using the trackball.  If this doesn't work for you, post your code, and ask a follow-up question.

Comment: Thnks alott Nate..Now i cn achieve that requirement using ur code.It worked. Now for better UI can i use Pill Button utility to make tabs like structure..???? And can this pill button can be used with java

Comment: The BlackBerry [Advanced UI open source project](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/tree/master/Advanced%20UI) has a [pill button in it](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/PillButtonField.java) that you could use for a Java app.